# Efficiency of Very Long StringBuilders

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I am currently developing an app on android with java.

Obviously there are very many situations that I have to use lots of String manipulation. I prefer using the class `SpannableStringBuilder` since it has the most functions, very easy to append or add spans to the string.

However I was curious about the internal implementation of the class so I read parts of the code in the java file of `SpannableStringBuilder`. I was quite surprised when I saw that, when I use `append()` or `replace()` functions on the stringbuilder, it just creates a new char array with the resulting length and copies all the characters in the original char array from start to end to the new array with the changed part together.

Now I am worried, since what i am working on is quite similar to a memo pad and I use `SpannableStringBuilder` and `append()` every input the user types. But since it's a memopad the user might even type up to more than several tens of thousands of characters. In that case, the `append()` or `replace()` function has to copy a whole bunch of characters every time the user types something with a keyboard... I think this should have a huge impact on performance.

Is this something I should be worried about? are there other ways to make continuously appendable stringbuilders?

Comment: A nice opportunity to make a unit test measuring the performance, and then improve upon the code and give the improved code back. I am afraid you may have stumbled on a case of "too complex features - keep it simple." Maybe related to concurrency as the data structures cannot be that hard.

Comment: So your suggesting that I design a new data structure that manages the string as multiple subdivided char arrays?

Comment: Don't worry about the performance before you faced it. Usually, it would not matter because tens thousands of characters is only roughly ten kb.

Comment: @Joshua good advice.. I should start testing first

Comment: it's not like that: see how often / when `SpannableStringBuilder#resizeFor()` method is called

Comment: @NamHoLee No, he is suggesting you write tests to see if you actually have a performance issue instead of jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @Manu @NamHoLee That what I meant.Write your programming first. See if there are any performance issues. If it exists, find its cause(s). May be `SpannableStringBuilder` is the bottleneck. Then, replace it with other implementation and try again.

Comment: Yes, first measure, making a repeatable test case with many inserts. Then try a _minimal_ optimisation of the old code: doing your own allocation in larger blocks, replacing `.length` with a smaller boundary. A profiler like that from the NetBeans IDE can shed light on bottle necks.